# How to re-trigger GetCustomUI() from ExcelDNA

Tags: excel, ribbon, excel-dna

I have, in ExcelDNA, created a custom ribbon (extending ExcelRibbon) and overridden the GetCustomUI() method to create a menu control from a list of strings. Basically:

```
public override string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID)
{
    string customUIXml =
    @"<customUI xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui' loadImage='LoadImage' onLoad='OnRibbonLoaded' >
        <ribbon>
        <tabs>
        <tab id='CustomTab' label='My Dynamic Tab'>
        <group id='SampleGroup' label='My Sample Group'>
        <menu description='description' enabled='true' id='menuItem' visible='true' size='normal' >";

    foreach (string itemName in _ItemNameList)
        customUIXml += $"<button id='btn_tool_{itemName}' label='{itemName}' onAction='MyMethod' />";

    customUIXml +=
        @"</menu>
        </group >
        </tab>
        </tabs>
        </ribbon>
      </customUI>";

    return customUIXml;
}
```

Because `_ItemNameList` is retrieved from a different file/system, I can't place this customUI tag directly into the .dna file (as far as I know) and hence I build it on load via the GetCustomUI().

As a proof of concept, the `onAction` method will add a new item to `_ItemNameList` when the user clicks on a menu item.

But how do I get Excel to call GetCustomUI again in order to have the XML rebuilt?

I have tried invalidating the ribbon object itself, but this does not trigger Excel to call GetCustomUI again.

The next best thing I can think of (although I'm still to test this) is to create a menu with a whole load of invisible 'placeholder' buttons (by specifying the getVisible callbacks) and when the user clicks on a button, just invalidate the button that needs to now become visible, showing the new item added to `_ItemNameList`. I still need to think through how to get the correct button reference though... This also feels a little dirty.

Any ideas how to have Excel rebuild the ribbon?
Also open to other ideas to allow me to add items to a menu in an ExcelRibbon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `dynamicMenu` control, which will trigger an event to let you dynamically set the contents of the menu, every time you click on it.

[image]

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnLoad">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="MyAwesomeRibbon" label="My Awesome Ribbon">
        <group id="MyDynamicGroup" label="Hello Dynamic!">
          <dynamicMenu id="MyDynamicMenu"
                       label="Click for Awesome"
                       getContent="OnGetContent"
                       invalidateContentOnDrop="true"
                       size="large"
                       imageMso="HappyFace" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Your `OnGetContent` method will get fired every time the user clicks on the ribbon button, so you can dynamically assemble the items.

e.g.

```
public string OnGetContent(IRibbonControl control)
{
    var menuXml = @"
        <menu xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui' itemSize='large'>
            <button id='SaveButton'
                    label='Save'
                    onAction='OnSave'
                    imageMso='FileSave' />

            <button id='AboutButton'
                    label='About...'
                    onAction='OnAbout'
                    imageMso='FileDocumentInspect' />
        </menu>";

    return menuXml;
}
```

Of course, you'd have to build this string dynamically from your list, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to pass an argument to the click handler?

Comment: @user626528 I think you are looking for the [`tag` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribboncontrol.tag) of the `IRibbonControl` - if not, please post a new question with more details