# Excel-DNA RibbonGallery implementation

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I am trying to implement a selection button/drop down menu (not combo box) in ExcelDNA - in VSTO terms it's a RibbonGallery - much like the bottom of the paste button or the Conditional Formatting in XL2013.

Is this possible? I don't need fancy graphics, just a list of text items on a single level menu. I would ideally add these items programatically on application launch.

[image: Drop down menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the **dynamicMenu** control. See this answer here on SO:

How to re-trigger GetCustomUI() from ExcelDNA
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033472

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks